# fetching values from dictionary. Range match on keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I created a dictionary `myDict` holding 10 million entries in the following form. Each entry in the dictionary represent `{(id, age): code}`

```
>>> myDict = {('1039', '68.0864'): '42731,42781,V4501', 
              ('1039', '68.1704'): '4770,4778,V071', 
              ('0845', '60.4476'): '2724,27800,4019', 
              ('0983', '63.3936'): '41401,4168,4240,V1582,V7281'
             }
```

A constant `ageOffset` is defined with value = `0.1`

Given an `(id,age)` tuple, how can I fetch all values from `myDict` which have key `(id, X)` where:

```
age <= X <= age+ageOffset
```

I need to perform this fetch operation 20 billion times.

```
Examples: 
1. 
myTup = ('1039', '68.0')
the answer is: '42731,42781,V4501'

2. 
myTup = ('0845', '60.0')
Ans : No value returned
```

Edit: 
Can I create a sub-dictionary, on the basis of partial match on the first element of the Key. I mean, If first element of the tuple Key matched, then create a subdictionary. According to my data, this wont be longer than a couple of hundreds. And then perform linear range search comparing the second element in the tuple key and finding the corresponding values.

Comment: can you use other data structure to optimize this? I think that changing that can improve performance and also make it easy to solve it

Comment: "*Given an `(id,age)` tuple*" -- are there constraints on the age you are looking up? Is it always whole? Always a multiple of `.1`?

Comment: I agree with @llazzaro, if you are going to do this 20 billion times, you should rethink the data structure and use numpy.

Comment: I am open with any data structure as far as it is efficient. I created dictionary because of it being  efficient? Which DS you are thinking of and why?

Comment: You *really* need to move away from using a dict here. Your only option is to scan *all* keys; if you have 10 million entries that is not going to perform well..

Comment: @user1140126: A dict is only efficient at looking up elements quickly *provided you know the key*. You don't know the exact keys, so then you have to scan.

Comment: @Rob, There is no constraint on age. It is just coincidence that in the example it is a whole number. It can be any float value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this operation 20 billion(!) times, you will have to preprocess your data a bit.

First, I would group by id:

```
def preprocess(data):
    from collections import defaultdict # Python 2.5+ only
    preprocessed = defaultdict(list)
    # group by id
    for (id, age), value in data.iteritems():
        preprocessed[id].append((float(age), value))
    # sort lists for binary search, see edit
    for key, value in preprocessed.iteritems():
        value.sort()
    return preprocessed
```

Result should look like this:

```
>>> preprocess(myDict)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
    '0845': [(60.4476, '2724,27800,4019')],
    '0983': [(63.3936, '41401,4168,4240,V1582,V7281')],
    '1039': [(68.0864, '42731,42781,V4501'), (68.1704, '4770,4778,V071')]}
```

If relatively few items share the same id, thus resulting in short lists, you might get away with filtering the list.

```
def lookup(data, id, age, age_offset=0.1):
    if id in data:
        return [value for x, value in data[id] if age <= x <= age+age_offset]
    else:
        return None     

lookup(preprocessed, '1039', 68.0) # Note that I use floats for age
['42731,42781,V4501']
```

However, if many items share the same id, you will have to traverse long lists, making the lookup relatively slow. In this case, you will have to apply further optimizations.

Edit: as suggested by @Andrey Petrov

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from itertools import islice, takewhile
def optimized_lookup(data, id, age, age_offset=0.1):
    if id in data:
        l = data[id]
        idx = bisect_left(l, age)
        return [a for a,v in takewhile(lambda (x, value): x <= age+age_offset, islice(l, idx, None))]
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: The most obvious optimization is to make use of the binary search algorithm.
To do this you first sort each of your small lists by age and then take the recipe from here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

Comment: Nice, didn't know about bisect.

Comment: @DanielHepper, Nice, it is working. I am now checking this on my actual input. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it in numpy, and though I haven't tested it I'm pretty confident it will be vastly faster than looping over the dictionary. I replaced the dictionary structure with a Numpy record array, and used np.where to locate the rows where they match the parameters you gave.

```
import numpy as np

myDict = {('1039', '68.0864'): '42731,42781,V4501', 
              ('1039', '68.1704'): '4770,4778,V071', 
              ('0845', '60.4476'): '2724,27800,4019', 
              ('0983', '63.3936'): '41401,4168,4240,V1582,V7281'
             }

records=[]
for k,v in myDict.iteritems():
    records.append([k[0], float(k[1]), v])

myArr = np.rec.fromrecords(records, formats='S10, f4, S100', 
                             names="ID, Age, Code")

def findInMyArray(arr, requestedID, requestedAge, tolerance=0.1):
    idx = np.where(((arr["Age"] - requestedAge) < tolerance) & (arr["ID"] == requestedID))
    return idx

idx = findInMyArray(myArr, "1039", 68.0, tolerance=0.1)
print "The index found is: ", idx
print "The values are: ", myArr["Code"][idx[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getr(t):
  id = float(t[0])
  age = float(t[1])
  os = 0.1
  rs = []
  correct_id=fixed[id]
  for k in correct_id.keys():
      if (k > age and k <= age + os):
          rs.append(correct_id.get(k))
  return rs

ct = {('1039', '68.0864'): '42731,42781,V4501',
      ('1039', '68.1704'): '4770,4778,V071',
      ('0845', '60.4476'): '2724,27800,4019',
      ('0983', '63.3936'): '41401,4168,4240,V1582,V7281' }

fixed={}

for k in ct:
    if not(float(k[0]) in fixed):
        fixed[float(k[0])]={}
    fixed[float(k[0])][float(k[1])] = ct[k]

print "1"
myTup = ('1039', '68.0')
assert(getr(myTup) == ['42731,42781,V4501'])

#the answer is: '42731,42781,V4501'

print "2"
myTup = ('0845', '60.0')
assert(getr(myTup) == [])
#Ans : No value returned
```